# Simple past or past participle in a CV?

Tags: past-tense, past-participles, conversational-deletion

On many CVs I see sentences like:

> • Achieved this.
>
> • Managed that.

I am assuming this isn't a case of [Conversational Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-the-subject-omitted-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask) and these tenses are past participles. 
So if I were to use an irregular verb I would write:

> • Done this.
>
> • Taken part in that.

Is that correct?

Comment: Apart from the necessary caution required when using **done** instead of **did**, all the possibilities given work

Comment: No. 1) Entries in this sort of list should (as a courtesy to your reader) have the same syntactic structure. Those *-ed* forms are ordinarily parsed as past-tense forms, not participles, and subsequent entries should follow suit. 2) Past participles in this sort of list are ordinarily parsed as passives, not perfects: *Granted this, Awarded that*; but if you want to mix those into your initial past-tense list they should be adjusted to *Was granted this, was awarded that*.

Comment: @Chris I am not sure I understand what you mean. Are you referring to [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37882/how-commonly-does-done-replace-did)?

Comment: @StoneyB So, if I understand correctly, when we write "Managed that" we mean "I managed that" but get rid of the subject. How is that different from conversational deletion (given a CV isn't an informal conversation)?

Comment: @Maurizio - Yes.  That is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

In a resume, I often see a list of bullets like this:

> - Awarded Best Employee 2014
> - Developed an app that did XYZ
> - Increased sales by 50%

...and so on.

In a resume, it's reasonable to assume that all of the listed accomplishments are about the subject of the resume. The "I" (or "I was", "I did", etc) is usually omitted - not because the resume is conversational, but because the subject is clear from context.

I wouldn't say "developed an app that did XYZ" as a sentence in conversation, because anyone listening wouldn't know who I was talking about. But on a document that has my name in bold up at the top, with details of my professional experience, "developed an app that did XYZ" clearly means that *I* developed that app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the past tense form, not the past participle. While it may not be a "conversational" context, the verb form is the same as it is in what is called "Conversational Deletion". It doesn't come across as informal in this context.